# readtable - read all columns as text in Matlab

Tags: matlab

When using Matlab `readtable(...)` ([link](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)) the function flexibly finds the best fitting field format (text, number) for each column:

```
tbl = readtable(filename);
```

one can specify to import dates as text as follows:

```
tbl = readtable(fileName,'DateTimeType','text');
```

However, since I am working with mixed data, I want to surpress that Matlab automatically sets their own format.

How can I import everything as text?

*Note: I know that you can add `'Format', '%s %s ...'`, but I do not wish to use this option as it requires knowing the number of columns beforehand (which I do not know)*

Comment: Have you checked *detectImportOptions* to get *opts* for *readtable*? It seems you can *setvartype* there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [`detectImportOptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detectimportoptions.html) and [`setvartype`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importoptions.setvartype.html) as follows:

```
opts = detectImportOptions(fileName);
opts = setvartype(opts, 'char');
tbl = readtable(fileName, opts, 'DatetimeType', 'text');
```